# Prevent malicious code in sandbox Java

Tags: java, sandbox

How to prevent an sandbox jvm with security manager from malicious code like an infinite loop which would cause 100% cpu usage of the jvm process and thread wastage

Answer (score 1):

There are certain things that it is not possible for the JVM sandbox to protect against.  These include:

- infinite loops
- code that creates large numbers of objects, or large sized objects
- code that leaks regular heap memory
- code that fills up PermGen ... in older JVMs where PermGen was an issue.

Some "resource hog" behavior can be blocked.  For example, the sandbox can prevent untrusted code from starting threads, or initiating I/O in ways that exhaust the file descriptor pool.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation